# Spring Data JPA JpaRepository.save(entity) not returning database default values

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a fairly simple problem. In a single transaction, my code looks something like this:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.setPropA("A");

c = myClassRepository.save(c);

c.setPropC("C");
```

Where my entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_CLASS")
public class MyClass {
  private String propA;
  private String propB;
  private String propC;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "PROP_A", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
  public String getPropA() { return propA; }
  public void   setPropA(String propA) { this.propA = propA; }

  @Column(name = "PROP_B", insertable = false)
  public String getPropB() { return propB; }
  public void   setPropB(String propB) { this.propB = propB; }

  @Column(name = "PROP_C")
  public String getPropC() { return propC; }
  public void   setPropC(String propC) { this.propC = propC; }
}
```

And the database is set up like this (Dialect = Oracle 11G)

```
CREATE TABLE MY_CLASS {
  PROP_A VARCHAR2 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  PROP_B VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'B' NOT NULL,
  PROP_C VARCHAR2
}
```

So, based on the code to persist the entity, I would think I'd get queries that look something like this:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.setPropA("A");

c = myClassRepository.saveAndFlush(c);
// INSERT INTO MY_CLASS (PROP_A, PROP_C) VALUES ("A", NULL)
// SELECT PROP_A, PROP_B, PROP_C FROM MY_CLASS -- to refresh `c`

c.setPropC("C");

// After transaction ends, flush change to `c.propC`
// UPDATE MY_CLASS SET PROP_B = "B", PROP_C = "C" WHERE PROP_A = "A"
```

... but the `SELECT` never happens. Why is the entity not refreshed?

This breaks because of the `UPDATE` that (immediately) follows the `INSERT` and `c.propB` is still `null`. I get a `ORA-01407: cannot update ("MY_SCHEMA"."MY_CLASS"."PROP_B") to NULL` stack trace.

I realize there are ways around this using `@PrePersist` or setting default values on `columnDefinition` in Java, but I shouldn't have to duplicate defaults.

Note: This worked before when I was using `org.hibernate.Session.saveOrUpdate()` instead of Spring Data JPA for this action.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't know that B is generated by the database, and that it has to read it after insert, unless you tell it to do so using the [`@Generated` annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Generated.html).

Comment: Good catch! Would `@GeneratedValue` be the JPA equivalent?

Comment: In my case, I have a column `modified_at` and default value is current datetime. The only thing that worked for me was [@UpdateTimestamp](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/UpdateTimestamp.html). I did not need to call `.flush()`.

Neither [@Generated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Generated.html) or [@GeneratedValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) annotations worked for me, even after using `.flush()` the field would still come back as null after a `.save()`.