# spring data auditing fields marked as updatable=false don't get set on the returned entity when updating

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, auditing

I'm using Spring Data's annotations to add auditing data to my entities when they are saved or updated. When I create the entity the `createdBy`, `createdDate`, `lastModifiedBy` and `lastModifiedDate` get set on the object returned by `repository.save()`.

```
ResourceEntity(id=ebbe1f3d-3359-4295-8c83-63eab21c4753, createdDate=2018-09-07T21:11:25.797, lastModifiedDate=2018-09-07T21:11:25.797, createdBy=5855070b-866f-4bc4-a18f-26b54f896a4b, lastModifiedBy=5855070b-866f-4bc4-a18f-26b54f896a4b)
```

Unfortunately, when I call `repository.save()` to update an existing entity the object returned does not have the `createdBy` and `createdDate` set.

```
 ResourceEntity(id=ebbe1f3d-3359-4295-8c83-63eab21c4753, createdDate=null, lastModifiedDate=2018-09-07T21:12:01.953, createdBy=null, lastModifiedBy=5855070b-866f-4bc4-a18f-26b54f896a4b)
```

All the fields are set correctly in the database and a call to `repository.findOne()` outside of my service class returns an object with all the fields set correctly.

```
ResourceEntity(id=ebbe1f3d-3359-4295-8c83-63eab21c4753, createdDate=2018-09-07T21:11:25.797, lastModifiedDate=2018-09-07T21:12:01.953, createdBy=5855070b-866f-4bc4-a18f-26b54f896a4b, lastModifiedBy=5855070b-866f-4bc4-a18f-26b54f896a4b)
```

But if I call `repository.findOne()` in the service right after calling `repository.save()` to update the entity I also get an object back with `createdBy` and `createdDate` set to null.

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity(name = "resource")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "resource")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ResourceEntity {

@Id
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")
private UUID id;

@CreatedDate
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private LocalDateTime createdDate;

@LastModifiedDate
private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

@CreatedBy
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")
private UUID createdBy;

@LastModifiedBy
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")
private UUID lastModifiedBy;
}
```

Here is my service:

```
@Component
public class ResourceService {
@Autowired
private ResourceRepository resourceRepository;

public ResourceEntity createResource(ResourceEntity resourceEntity) {
    return saveResource(resourceEntity);
}

public ResourceEntity updateResource(ResourceEntity resourceEntity) {
    return saveResource(resourceEntity);
}

public ResourceEntity getResource(UUID resourceId) {
    return resourceRepository.findOne(resourceId);
}

private ResourceEntity saveResource(ResourceEntity resourceEntity) {
    ResourceEntity savedResourceEntity = resourceRepository.save(resourceEntity);
    return savedResourceEntity;
}
}
```

Here is my test:

```
def "Test update"() {
    given:
    UUID id = aRandom.uuid()
    Resource resource = aRandom.resource().id(id).build()
    Resource savedResource = resourceClient.createResource(resource)

    when:
    Resource updatedResource = aRandom.resource().id(id).build()
    updatedResource = resourceClient.updateResource(updatedResource)

    then:
    Resource result = resourceClient.getResource(id)
    assert result.id == updatedResource.id
    assert result.createdBy == updatedResource.createdBy
    assert result.creationDate == updatedResource.creationDate
    assert result.lastModifiedBy == updatedResource.lastModifiedBy
    assert result.lastModifiedDate == updatedResource.lastModifiedDate
}
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior. When updatable = false is set, then you can update this field.

Comment: I would argue that is not the expected behavior as the spring docs say:

_Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely._

If we're supposed to use the returned instance then it better accurately reflect what is in the database. Yes, `update=false` prevents the `save()` call from updating the created fields but they should be populated in the returned object with what is in the database.

Comment: For a simple solution, you can fetch the Entity again from DB. Now this Entity will have the field that was previously updated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42023070/updating-an-entity-with-updatable-false-set-the-field-to-null

Answer (score 1):

Years after the original question and it's still an issue.

While not a perfect solution, I ended up fetching (via `findById()`) the existing entity and manually setting the `@CreatedBy` and `@CreatedDate` fields on the new entity before performing the update. It's both surprising and frustrating that JPA's auditing framework doesn't automatically handle this or provide a better way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried before like this when i need to add audit info.

I have a `DataConfig` class like this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<UUID> auditorProvider() {
        return new YourSecurityAuditAware();
    }

    @Bean
    public DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider() {
        return () -> Optional.of(Instant.from(ZonedDateTime.now()));
    }
}
```

Now you need `AuditorAware` class to get audit info.
So this class will be like this ;

```
public class XPorterSecurityAuditAware implements AuditorAware<UUID> {

    @Override
    public Optional<UUID> getCurrentAuditor() {
        //you can change UUID format as well
        return Optional.of(UUID.randomUUID());
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.