# Spring Data MongoDB: how to avoid @CreatedBy and @CreatedDate fields update?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring-Boot 2.5.0 and MongoDB to persist some documents.
Here the [Github Project](https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/MongoDBAuditing).

For each document I also need to automatically save some auditing info, therefore I extend the following class:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.*;
import java.time.Instant;

@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class AuditingDocument {
    @Version
    private Long version;

    @CreatedBy
    private String creator;
    @CreatedDate
    private Instant created;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modifier;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant modified;
}
```

E.g. let's consider the `Book` class:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Book extends AuditingDocument {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;
}
```

The problem I'm encountering is that when I update the document, via `JSON`/`REST API`,
I am able to alter/overwrite the value of the `@CreatedBy` and `@CreatedDate` fields.

Meaning that if the fields are not provided then the resulting values will be saved as null, otherwise, it will save the new value for the creator and created fields.

This should not be allowed since it represents a security issue in most use cases.
How can I make these two fields not updatable? If the creator is present there is no need to update it later. Such values are automatically populated hence there could be no error requiring to update the value.

I found other similar questions but they are about JPA not MongoDB, e.g.

- [@Createdby @CreatedDate are null after entity is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64140558/createdby-createddate-are-null-after-entity-is-updated) (JPA)

Here they use

```
@Column(name = "created_by", updatable = false)
```

to protect the fields from updates.
Unfortunately, the `@Field` for MongoDB has no such property.

How can I protect all such fields from being modified after they are already present in the database? Obviously, I need a solution that is able to scale with all the `@Document` entities without needing to handle each one separately, e.g. by reading it manually from the DB and fixing the document to be saved first.

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to implement this behaviour by overriding the `doUpdate` method in a `MongoTemplate` subclass.

```
public class CustomMongoTemplate extends MongoTemplate {
    public CustomMongoTemplate(MongoClient mongoClient, String databaseName) {
        super(mongoClient, databaseName);
    }

    public CustomMongoTemplate(MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory) {
        super(mongoDbFactory);
    }

    public CustomMongoTemplate(MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory, MongoConverter mongoConverter) {
        super(mongoDbFactory, mongoConverter);
    }

    @Override
    protected UpdateResult doUpdate(String collectionName, Query query, UpdateDefinition update, Class<?> entityClass, boolean upsert, boolean multi) {
        Document updateDocument = update.getUpdateObject();
        List<?> list = this.find(query, entityClass);

        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            Object existingObject = list.get(0);
            Document existingDocument = new Document();
            this.getConverter().write(existingObject, existingDocument);

            // Keep the values of the existing document
            if (existingDocument.keySet().containsAll(Arrays.asList("version", "creator", "created"))) {
//                Long version = existingDocument.getLong("version");
                String creator = existingDocument.getString("creator");
                Date created = existingDocument.getDate("created");

                System.out.println("Creator: " + creator);
                System.out.println("Created: " + created);

//                updateDocument.put("version", version++);
                updateDocument.put("creator", creator);
                updateDocument.put("created", created);

                System.out.println("Update Document");
                System.out.println(updateDocument.toJson());
            }

            return super.doUpdate(collectionName, query, Update.fromDocument(updateDocument), entityClass, upsert, multi);
        } else {
            return super.doUpdate(collectionName, query, update, entityClass, upsert, multi);
        }
    }
}
```

This approach is partially working, meaning that after I call the save method of a repository, the update's object does not overwrite the existing creator and created fields, however for some reason the save method returns an object with null values for creator and created, even if in the database the document has such values.

I also tried to get all the documents of the collection at once and their values (creator, created) are correctly populated and returned by the API endpoint. It seems like the `doUpdate()` method is messing up with something, but I can't get with wath.

**UPDATE 2**

Each document is saved in the DB using a Service implementing this interface, which simply calls the corresponding `save()` method of the MongoRepository.

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.IterableUtils;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface EntityService<T, K> {
    MongoRepository<T, K> getRepository();

    default Optional<T> findById(K id) {
        return this.getRepository().findById(id);
    }

    default List<T> findAll(){
        return this.getRepository().findAll();
    }

    default List<T> findAllByIds(List<K> ids){
        return IterableUtils.toList(this.getRepository().findAllById(ids));
    }

    default T save(T entity) {
        return this.getRepository().save(entity);
    }

    default List<T> save(Iterable<T> entities) {
        return this.getRepository().saveAll(entities);
    }

    default void delete(T entity) {
        this.getRepository().delete(entity);
    }

    default void delete(Iterable<T> entity) {
        this.getRepository().deleteAll(entity);
    }
}
```

and this is the corresponding `@Repository`

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends MongoRepository<Book, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Book> {}
```

**UPDATE 3**

The RestController calls this method, where the service is the one defined above:

```
default T save(T entity) {
    return this.convert(this.getService().save(this.decode(entity)));
}
```

and these are the convert and decode methods:

```
    @Override
    public BookDTO convert(Book source) {
        return BookDTO.builder()
                .id(source.getId())
                // Auditing Info
                .version(source.getVersion())
                .creator(source.getCreator())
                .created(source.getCreated())
                .modifier(source.getModifier())
                .modified(source.getModified())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public Book decode(BookDTO target) {
        return Book.builder()
                .id(target.getId())
                // Auditing Info
                .version(target.getVersion())
//                .creator(target.getCreator())
//                .created(target.getCreated())
//                .modifier(target.getModifier())
//                .modified(target.getModified())
                .build();
    }
```

**Update 4**

I just created a Spring Boot/Java 16 MWP to reproduce the error on [GitHub](https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/MongoDBAuditing).

This is the RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BookController {

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    @PostMapping(value = "/book")
    public Book save(@RequestBody Book entity) {
        return this.bookRepository.save(entity);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/book/test")
    public Book test() {
        Book book = Book.builder().name("Book1").build();
        return this.bookRepository.save(book);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/books")
    public List<Book> books() {
        return this.bookRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

If I update the document via the `"/book"` endpoint, the document in the DB is saved correctly (with the existing creator & created fields), but it is returned with null values for these fields by the Rest Controller.

However, the `"/books"` returns all the books with all the fields correctly populated.

It seems like there is something between `the doUpdate` method and the controller return that sets these fields to null.

**Update 5**

I created some tests in order to better check the save method of the `BookRepository`.

What I found:

1. The save method correctly creates the book at the first time, with all the auditing vields (`version, creator, created, modifier, modified`) populated as expected.
2. The save method correctly updates the existing book in the DB, keeping the existing values for the `creator` and `created` fields for subsequent find queries.
3. The save method returns an object with creator and created fields set to null (but in the DB the document has all auditing fields populated).

Here are my test methods (also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/MongoDBAuditing/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/demo/repository/BookRepositoryTests.java)).

```
import com.example.demo.domain.Book;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@SpringBootTest
@Rollback
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class BookRepositoryTests {
    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    @Transactional
    public void testCreateBook() {
        this.doCreateBook("1001", "Java Programming");
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    @Transactional
    public void testUpdateBookAndFind() {
        this.doCreateBook("1002", "Python Programming");
        Book existingBook = this.bookRepository.findById("1002").orElse(null);

        // Check Existing Book
        Assertions.assertNotNull(existingBook);

        // Update
        existingBook.setCreated(null);
        existingBook.setCreator(null);
        existingBook.setModifier(null);
        existingBook.setModified(null);

        this.bookRepository.save(existingBook);
        Book existingUpdatedBook = this.bookRepository.findById("1002").orElse(null);

        // Check Existing Updated Book (Working)
        Assertions.assertNotNull(existingUpdatedBook);

        Assertions.assertNotNull(existingUpdatedBook.getCreator());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(existingUpdatedBook.getCreated());

        Assertions.assertNotNull(existingUpdatedBook.getModifier());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(existingUpdatedBook.getModified());
    }

    @Test
    @Order(3)
    @Transactional
    public void testUpdateBookDirect() {
        this.doCreateBook("1003", "Go Programming");
        Book existingBook = this.bookRepository.findById("1003").orElse(null);

        // Check Existing Book
        Assertions.assertNotNull(existingBook);

        // Update
        existingBook.setCreated(null);
        existingBook.setCreator(null);
        existingBook.setModifier(null);
        existingBook.setModified(null);

        Book updatedBook = this.bookRepository.save(existingBook);

        // Check Updated Book (Not working)
        Assertions.assertNotNull(updatedBook);

        Assertions.assertNotNull(updatedBook.getCreator());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(updatedBook.getCreated());

        Assertions.assertNotNull(updatedBook.getModifier());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(updatedBook.getModified());
    }

    private void doCreateBook(String bookID, String bookName) {
        // Create Book
        Book book = Book.builder().id(bookID).name(bookName).build();
        Book createdBook = this.bookRepository.save(book);

        Assertions.assertNotNull(createdBook);
        Assertions.assertEquals(bookID, createdBook.getId());
        Assertions.assertEquals(bookName, createdBook.getName());

        // Check Auditing Fields
        Assertions.assertNotNull(createdBook.getVersion());

        Assertions.assertNotNull(createdBook.getCreator());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(createdBook.getCreated());

        Assertions.assertNotNull(createdBook.getModifier());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(createdBook.getModified());
    }
}
```

In synthesis, only the `testUpdateBookDirect()` method's assertions are not working. It seems there's some sort of interceptor right after the `CustomMongoTemplate.doUpdate()` method that overwrites these fields (creator, created).

Comment: Do you want the fields to appear when the object is requested via the REST API?

Comment: Yes, both the request and response objects have these fields. I just want to ignore them when saving the document, in order to keep the values present in the DB. The first time they are automatically populated by MongoDB auditing interceptors.

Comment: So to be clear,  you want these values to be present in the initial post and not determined by your server?

Comment: No, they are always determined by the server at the Document creation time, just the subsequent requests/updates must not be able to alter/modify the existing values in the DB, even if the request body has these fields with arbitrary values. They should be always ignored on requests and be generated by the server. The user must not be able to alter them on subsequent updates of the document, just other fields should be updatable.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your service class where you are performing update?

Comment: Sure, by the way I'm just using the MongoRepository interface to save the documents. I've updated the question.

Comment: Yes, this part is correct. I want to see service logic where you are doing the conversion from DTO to model and passing it to the save method. Can you provide that?

Comment: @Harshit ok, I have updated the question with the DTO convert & decode methods

Comment: @1Z10, Instead of manual coversion, you can use orika mapper to convert between pojos. Create a base model & base DTO and add global config for them where you can exclude created and modified fields.

Comment: I'll sure try the Orika mapper for DTOs thanks. What about the actual problem of maintaining the existing values in the DB for creator and created fields of all documents? Do you think there is something wrong in the doUpdate method?

Comment: did you add an `auditingProvider`?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/MongoDBAuditing/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/configuration/DatabaseAuditingConfiguration.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution or workaround is to:

1. extend the `MongoTemplate` class
2. override the `doUpdate` method
3. Combine the repository `save` and `find` methods to update and return the updated object with the auditing fields correctly populated. This is required since for some reason the `repository.save` method returns null for the auditing fields (`creator`, `created`) even if they are then correctly populated in the DB.

Here we need to override the `doUpdate` method of the `MongoTemplate`.

```
@Override
protected UpdateResult doUpdate(String collectionName, Query query, UpdateDefinition update, Class<?> entityClass, boolean upsert, boolean multi) {
    Document updateDocument = update.getUpdateObject();
    List<?> list = this.find(query, entityClass);

    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        Object existingObject = list.get(0);
        Document existingDocument = new Document();
        this.getConverter().write(existingObject, existingDocument);

        // Keep the values of the existing document
        if (existingDocument.keySet().containsAll(Arrays.asList("version", "creator", "created"))) {
            String creator = existingDocument.getString("creator");
            Date created = existingDocument.getDate("created");

            System.out.println("Creator: " + creator);
            System.out.println("Created: " + created);

            updateDocument.put("creator", creator);
            updateDocument.put("created", created);

            System.out.println("Update Document");
            System.out.println(updateDocument.toJson());
        }

        return super.doUpdate(collectionName, query, Update.fromDocument(updateDocument), entityClass, upsert, multi);
    } else {
        return super.doUpdate(collectionName, query, update, entityClass, upsert, multi);
    }
}
```

In the end I use a service that calls the repository for the save and find operations. This is the interface it implements.

```
public interface EntityService<T extends MongoDBDocument<K>, K> {
    MongoRepository<T, K> getRepository();

    default T save(T entity) {
        // First save it
        this.getRepository().save(entity);

        // Then find it by ID
        return this.getRepository().findById(entity.getId()).orElse(entity);
    }

    default List<T> save(Iterable<T> entities) {
        // First save them
        List<T> savedEntities = this.getRepository().saveAll(entities);
        List<K> savedEntitiesIDs = savedEntities.stream().map(entity -> entity.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Then find them by IDs
        return IterableUtils.toList(this.getRepository().findAllById(savedEntitiesIDs));
    }
}
```

In this way I able to do what I was looking for:

1. Let the auditing fields (version, creator, created, modifier, modified) be generated automatically by the BE.
2. Return these fields via API and DTOs.
3. Use the same DTO interface for `save` and `update` API endpoints.
4. Ignore the auditing values coming from the outside via APIs.
5. Never have the auditing fields saved to null or wrong values in the DB.
6. Return the correct & updated auditing fields after an update API call.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want requests to overwrite your audit fields (or any other fields for that matter) then one approach is to have different classes for your data model and for your DTOs and just convert from one to the other on the way in and the way out (Lombok builders make this super easy).

While there is an overhead for the conversion, plus the need to maintain the two classes, it does isolate your data model from the public facing requirements of your endpoint.

e.g. Java uses `SNAKE_CASE` for enums, but for some crazy reason you need to use `kebab-case` on your APIs.

Or you have a multi tenanted service where you have to persist the tenant in the DB, but don't need or want to expose it via DTOs.

Comment: I'm already using DTOs, but I need to return also the auditing info as the API output.
The problem is on the API input, where if the DTO has null or missing fields (creator, created) they will be mapped as null to the entity before saving, hence resulting in null fields in the DB. i need a way to just keep the existing values for these two fields and the CustomMongoTemplate seems almost ok, just the value returned after save has missing creator, created but in the DB they are populated correctly, and they are returned correctly on next API calls.

Comment: So what I sometimes do (depends on how complex my model is) is have a request class, a data model class and another response class. e.g. the POST body won't have an id field, but the response (and data model) classes will. Same with audit fields - I don't want users being able to set them. It might seem overkill at first, but another benefit is on request classes, I would ignore unknown fields etc. and on response classes, its not possible for there to be unknown fields. Another benefit is the Swagger generated can be worded to be clearer since its doing one thing not two.

Comment: You could save some typing by having your response DTO extend your request DTO and add the id and audit fields there, but I use Lombok as much as I can and inheritance just gets in the way.

Comment: I understand your approach, however I would like to still
share the auditing info on response while ignoring it on requests and keeping the existing creator and created fields. To do this once for all entities/dtos the only approach seems to customize/extend the MongoTemplate. As in the update, it is partially working right now. Probably I've missed some steps there.

Comment: Another two ideas. 1. write custom update statements that don't update these fields. But again, that's not helping with what you're trying to do e.g. write some code that handles "standard" fields of all your entities. 2. move the audit info into a separate immutable collection. Have a link/FK back to the original entity (the id) and record an event type (CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE) along with your timestamp and user info. This might provide other benefits, like auditing concurrent updates that otherwise might get lost. You could use this collection to audit all entities too.